# rake aborted! undefined method `text_area' for class `ActionView::Base'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, activesupport

I am very confused by a sudden problem with running rake tasks:

```
softwareclick:/myapp/current# rake my_task --trace
(in /myapp/releases/20100621162444)
** Invoke my_task (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `text_area' for class `ActionView::Base'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:33:in `alias_method'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:33:in `alias_method_chain'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/gems/lipsiadmin-5.1.2/lib/view/helpers/view_helper.rb:11:in `included'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/gems/lipsiadmin-5.1.2/lib/lipsiadmin.rb:41:in `include'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/gems/lipsiadmin-5.1.2/lib/lipsiadmin.rb:41
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/gems/lipsiadmin-5.1.2/lib/lipsiadmin.rb:40:in `class_eval'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/gems/lipsiadmin-5.1.2/lib/lipsiadmin.rb:40
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/config/environment.rb:12
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/myapp/releases/20100621162444/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:238:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:238:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

I run a passenger/nginx app on debian with ruby 1.8.5 and the following gems installed:

```
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
ancestry (1.2.0)
chronic (0.2.3)
fastthread (1.0.7)
git (1.2.5)
haml (3.0.12)
hoe (2.6.1)
json (1.4.3)
json_pure (1.4.3)
lipsiadmin (5.1.2)
nokogiri (1.4.2)
passenger (2.2.14)
postgres (0.7.9.2008.01.28)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
RedCloth (4.2.3)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
sitemap_generator (0.3.3)
texticle (1.0.2)
version (0.9.2)
whenever (0.4.2)
```

Due to the --trace I think it's something between lipsiadmin and active_support, but I simply can't figure out how to go forward.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for your help,

Val

Comment: Why are you vendoring Rails when you have the gem installed on the server also. Vendoring rails with gems is imho one of the most common bad habits people are doing...

Comment: Hi Tanel, I admit I did that in the beginning of my noobish development. But as I was trying to clean up for the recent deployment I ran into some trouble with the lower ruby version on my new server (debian, ruby 1.8.5) so I figured gems like sanitize who depend on a higher ruby version should be vendorized ...

Comment: Hey that actually did something for me. I can run rake gems -list now!
- [I] RedCloth = 4.2.3
- [I] ancestry 
   - [R] activerecord >= 2.1.0
- [F] acts_as_sanitiled 
   - [I] nokogiri ~> 1.3.3
   - [F] sanitize ~> 1.1.0
      - [I] nokogiri ~> 1.3.3
   - [I] RedCloth 
- [F] sanitize 
   - [I] nokogiri ~> 1.3.3
- [I] whenever 
   - [I] chronic >= 0.2.3
      - [I] hoe >= 1.2.1
         - [I] rubyforge >= 2.0.4
            - [I] json_pure >= 1.1.7
         - [R] rake >= 0.8.7
- [I] texticle 
- [I] lipsiadmin = 5.1.2
   - [I] haml 
   - [R] rails >= 2.2.1
- [I] sitemap_generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the rake task look like? Are you including a dependency on :environment?

Do any other rake tasks work?

Remember that rake does NOT start up the rails stack unless your task has an :environment dependency.

[Jason's rake overview](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial)

UPDATED:
My further suggestion, in the comments, was the right answer:

Gems, and plugins, can have dependencies on each other that require specific load order. So the solution is to remove gems/plugins to find which one is causing the problem. Then add it back into the system and choose the load order explicitly.

Comment: Hi, bad news, it's all the rake tasks ...

This one starts like this:

    task :fetch_regnow => :environment do
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'zlib'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'active_record'

The rest should just work. I haven't changed a thing in here.

As far as I can see all these dependencies are met.

I actually get the same result for "rake gems -list"

Comment: Maybe a gem is trying to call methods before all the libraries are loaded. I'd do some binary searching-first uninstall any newish gems that you suspect. Then add them back slowly to find the culprit.

Comment: Hmmm I would say I am done checking that out ... so would that mean, that perhabs lipsiadmin calls for text_area before the ActionView::Base is loaded? If so or similar, do you know a way to prioritize those guys?

Comment: Hey Larry, not sure if you are reading this, but you were pointing me in the right direction. I had a bunch of gems loaded randomly before their dependencies were loaded. I removed them all and did a new deploy with rake gems:install to get them installed correctly. If you like you can post this as the answer and I will be happy to accept it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Oh wait, I'll accept the one that's posted, sorry for being chaotic ;-)

Comment: Glad it worked out. I had the same problem with some plugins order a while back.